# How to disable password reset based on auth plugin?

Tags: moodle

I am using Moodle 3.11.

I created a plugin that authenticates and creates user based on an external API.
I would like that user that have been authenticated/created based on my plugin (or basically all normal users) cannot use "password forgot" functionality. However, I would like that my admins still can reset their passwords.

Is this possible somehow? Did not find much related in `auth_plugin_base`  class in `lib/authlib.php`

This is my core `auth.php` plugin:

```
class auth_plugin_myapi extends auth_plugin_base {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->authtype = 'myapi';
    }

    private static $userinfo = null;

    private $cohort;

    /**
     * Authenticate user against external API
     *
     * @param string $username Username to authenticate
     * @param string $password Password to authenticate
     * @return bool Returns true if the user was successfully authenticated, false otherwise.
     */
    public function user_login($username, $password) {

        // make API call to check authentication
        // also get user data and store in $userinfo
    }

    public function get_userinfo($username) {
        // Return userdata of user from external API
        //  if username matches  
        $user = self::$userinfo;

        if ($user == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($user->username !== $username) {
            return false;
        }
        return (array) $user;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true since this plugin only uses the external API for login validation.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function prevent_local_passwords() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, users can not reset their password for your custom login.

If you want to enable it, you would need to overwrite and change the can_reset_password method:

```
/**
 * Returns true if plugin allows resetting of internal password.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function can_reset_password() {
    //override if needed
    return false;
}
```

Per default its set to false. If a user try's to reset his password and logged in with your auth plugin, he receives this email:

> Hi XXX,
>
> Someone (probably you) has requested a new password for your account
> on 'We-Evolve.World'.
>
> Unfortunately passwords cannot be reset on this site. Please contact
> the site administrator Admin User

Your admin was probably registered differently and can therefore reset his password.